# How do I get the overload through reflection at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, reflection

Since where I work force me to use stored procedures and I haven't been around long enough to prevent it I have customized LiNQ to SQL code generation for all our stored procedures. Yes that's right we have stored procedures for ALL our data access and since **we don't have table access** it means that we often end up with 3 classes for all "entities". Now, I am drawing near completion of the latest changes when I hit a wall.

The following code does not work and the reason being that it is calling itself but I need to get the overload. The reason for this is that it's impossible to keep track of 40 parameters so I generate a "dynamic" class when the project builds.

```
[Function(Name="dbo.user_insert")]
public IList<ProcedureResult> UserInsert(UserInsertObj userInsertObj)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), 
        userInsertObj.UserId, userInsertObj.ProductId, userInsertObj.FromIp, 
        userInsertObj.CampaignName, userInsertObj.Campaign, userInsertObj.Login, 
        userInsertObj.Password, userInsertObj.Nickname, userInsertObj.Pin, userInsertObj.Language, 
        userInsertObj.Currency, userInsertObj.Country, userInsertObj.Region, userInsertObj.Birthday, 
        userInsertObj.FirstName, userInsertObj.MiddleName, userInsertObj.LastName, 
        userInsertObj.Address1, userInsertObj.Address2, userInsertObj.Address3, userInsertObj.Zip, 
        userInsertObj.City, userInsertObj.Timezone, userInsertObj.Email, userInsertObj.EmailNotify, 
        userInsertObj.Gender, userInsertObj.Phone, userInsertObj.MobileCc, userInsertObj.MobileNr, 
        userInsertObj.MobileModel, userInsertObj.Referral, userInsertObj.GroupId, 
        userInsertObj.StreetNumber, userInsertObj.StreetName);

    return new List<ProcedureResult> 
    { 
        new ProcedureResult
        {
            Name = "userId",
            Value = result.GetParameterValue(0),
            Type = typeof(System.Nullable<System.Int32>) 
        }
    };
}
```

I played around with using something like the below but have no idea which overload to use and searching MSDN I haven't come close to anything useful yet.

```
((MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()).DeclaringType.GetMethod("", new Type[] {})
```

How would I achieve getting the overload from the **CurrentMethod**?

EDIT: clarified that we are not allowed to use the database tables.

Comment: Seems like a bizare way to call stored procedures using LinqToSQL, you do know you can just map them to methods on your DataContext class don't you?

Comment: @Ben, thank you! I have updated the question in regard to your comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Reflection to Invoke an Overloaded Method in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223495/how-to-use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overloaded-method-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot about linq! In this particular scenario I have only two methods one containing 1 parameter and one containing all the other parameters so a simple (see below) works fine:

```
method.DeclaringType.GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "UserInsert" 
           && x.GetParameters().Count() > 1)
    .Single()
```