# Ambiguous match found when accessing dll

Tags: c#, reflection, dllimport, overloading

I am trying load a function in a dll. The dll is loaded but just at the place of invoking the function, I am getting an exception

> Ambiguous match found

Here is the code snippet.

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(DLLPATH);
if (dll != null)
{
    Type Tp = dll.GetType("ABCD.FooClass");
    if (Tp != null)
    {
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Tp);

        if (obj != null)
        {                            
            List = (List<String>)obj.GetType().GetMethod("Foo").Invoke(obj, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("obj is null");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Type is null");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Dll is not loaded");

Console.ReadKey();
```

The method which I am calling (i.e `Foo`), **does not accept any parameters** and it is an overloaded method. Is that the place where I am going wrong or is it some other place?

Is there another way to invoke such methods which does not accept any parameters? I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223495/how-to-use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overloaded-method-in-net) but it is not working.

Comment: Sample code without all LoadLibrary/CreateInstance would likely show problem more clearly - please try to make simple sample with simplified "FooClass" and call to Invoke. (assuming you get exception there).

Comment: Did you load the assembly multiple times?

Comment: @Oliver : I am loading assembly for one time only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `Type.GetMethod(string methodName)` throws the exception you mentioned if there is more than one method with the specified name ( see [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332482%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) ). As `Foo` is an overload as you say I suspect that there are multiple `Foo` methods in the same DLL. If you have for example the methods :

```
IList<string> Foo()

IList<string> Foo(object someParameter)
```

The method `GetMethod(string methodName)` can not determine which one you want to have. In this case you should use the method `GetMethods` and determine the correct method on your own.

Answer (score 11):

If there is an overload and you want to invoke the method with no parameters this is the correct solution:

```
MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Foo", new Type[] { });
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys for your help.!!

As I told you, the method (i.e FOO) which I was calling, is overloaded. I did not used GetMethod() properly I suppose. Now, I found a solution using GetMethods() function.

I changed my code in following way and it worked.!!

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(DLLPATH);
if (dll != null)
{
   Type Tp = dll.GetType("ABCD.FooClass");
   if (Tp != null)
   {
      Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Tp);
      if (obj != null)
      {                            
         MethodInfo[] AllMethods = obj.GetType().GetMethods();
         MethodInfo Found = AllMethods.FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.Name == "Foo" && mi.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
         if (Found != null)
             List = (List<String>)Found.Invoke(obj, null);           
      }
      else
        Console.WriteLine("obj is null");       
   }
    else
     Console.WriteLine("Type is null");
 }
  else
     Console.WriteLine("Dll is not loaded");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

My "Ambiguous match found" was I had a textbox in the ASCX(frontend) named Bio, a data element named Bio in a listview <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Bio")%> and I named a string variable Bio in .CS.

No build errors or "redlines" but generated an error at runtime.  I renamed the variables differently and the error went away. The prgrammer who wrote the code didn't follow naming conventions such as BioTxt.  This would of eliminated the error.