# Why isn't [[carries_dependency]] the default in C++?

Tags: c++, stdatomic, relaxed-atomics, carries-dependency

I know that `memory_order_consume` has been deprecated, but I'm trying to understand the logic that went into the original design and how `[[carries_dependency]]` and `kill_dependency` were supposed to work.  For that, I would like a specific example of code that would break on an IBM PowerPC or DEC alpha or even a hypothetical architecture with a hypothetical compiler that fully implemented consume semantics in C++11 or C++14.

The best I can come up with is an example like this:

```
int v;
std::atomic<int*> ap;

void
thread_1()
{
  v = 1;
  ap.store(&v, std::memory_order_release);
}

int
f(int *p [[carries_dependency]])
{
  return v;
}

void
thread_2()
{
  int *p;
  while (!(p = ap.load(std::memory_order_consume)))
    ;
  int v2 = f(p);
  assert(*p == v2);
}
```

I understand that the assertion could fail in this code.  However, is it the case that the assertion is *not* supposed to fail if you remove `[[carries_dependency]]` from `f`?  If so, why is that the case?  After all, you requested a `memory_order_consume`, so why would you expect other accesses to `v` to reflect acquire semantics?  If removing `[[carries_dependency]]` does not make the code correct, then what's an example where `[[carries_dependency]]` (or making `[[carries_dependency]]` the default for all variables) breaks otherwise correct code?

The only thing I can think is that maybe this has to do with register spills?  If a function spills a register onto the stack and later re-loads it, this could break the dependency chain.  So maybe `[[carries_dependency]]` makes things efficient in some cases (says no need to issue memory barrier in the caller before calling this function) but also requires the *callee* to issue a memory barrier before any register spills or calling another function, which could be less efficient in other cases?  I'm grasping at straws here, though, so would still love to hear from someone who understands this stuff...

Answer (score 2):

`return v` doesn't have a data dependency on `int *p`, so you'd need `acquire` not `consume` for `ap.load(consume)` / `f(p)` to synchronize with the release store.

If you'd used `return *p` then this would be sufficient thanks to dependency ordering, because that load would have a data dependency on the earlier load, no way for the CPU to generate the address earlier and thus load from `v` before the load from `ap` that saw the value you were waiting for.

Promoting dropping the dependency-ordering stuff effectively requires promoting `consume` to `acquire` by using a memory barrier before the function call.

DEC Alpha would *always* need a barrier even for `consume` to work, i.e. it had to promote `consume` to `acquire` because the ISA didn't guarantee dependency ordering by the hardware.

Some ISAs (mostly just x86) are so strongly ordered they don't need a barrier because every load is an acquire load, not reordered with other loads.  Or at least giving the illusion of not being reordered; actual implementations speculatively load early but nuke the pipeline if mis-speculation is detected, i.e. where a cache line isn't still valid by the time the load was architecturally allowed to happen.

So x86 and Alpha would likely still work even with the `[[carries-dependency]]` version, because they're either too strong or too weak for `mo_consume` to be something the hardware can actually do (more cheaply than `mo_acquire`).

For Alpha it would depend where the compiler put the barrier; it could put it after `f(p)`'s `return v`, only before the `*p` that actually depends on the consume load.  Or it could just promote consume to acquire on the spot at the load, like compilers do now (since consume is deprecated after proving too hard to support in its current design.)

---

As for **why ISO C++11 decided to promote `consume` results to effectively `acquire` when passing across function boundaries**, that might have been a usability consideration.  But also performance.  **Without that, compilers would lose the ability to do some optimizations on incoming function args.**

e.g. `int ready = foo.load(consume);` / `if(ready == 1) return non_atomic[ready-ready];` is required to make asm that has a data dependency on the consume-load result, unlike normal when the compiler would just optimize it to `return *non_atomic`.

(You might be familiar with x86 `xor eax,eax` being a good way to zero a register.  In weakly-ordered ISAs that guarantee dependency ordering, like ARM, `eor r0, r0,r0` is *guaranteed not* to break the dependency on the old value of `r0`.)

Also constant-propagation in branches like `if(ready == 1)` should be possible; code inside that `if` can only run when `ready` has the constant value `1`.  So even if we weren't cancelling it out, `non_atomic[ready]` can't be optimized to `non_atomic[1];`.

If every incoming function arg potentially carried a dependency, compilers would not be able to do those usual optimizations on any function args or values derived from them.

---

Related re: what `consume` is about and/or its deprecation, and that it's still used in a hand-rolled way with `volatile` in Linux kernel code (e.g. RCU):

- [[[carries_dependency]] what it means and how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113244/carries-dependency-what-it-means-and-how-to-implement)
- [When should you not use [[carries_dependency]]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126983/when-should-you-not-use-carries-dependency)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, I already understand dependency ordering and what consume semantics are supposed to do, so really my question is about `[[carries_dependency]]`.  Would `f` work on DEC alpha if I deleted the `[[carries_dependency]]`?

Comment: @user3188445: It would work everywhere if you deleted the `[[carries_dependency]]`; that would require `thread_2()` to do something like `atomic_thread_fence(acquire)` before calling `f`, because it couldn't count on `f` to to respect the data dependencies on `int *p` (if there were any, e.g. if it had been written as `return *p`).  Since it guarantees that even non-dependent loads would happen-after `ap.load(consume)`, it effectively promotes it to acquire semantics.

Comment: (At least that's my understanding, and what I thought I said in my answer, e.g. in the text around *why ISO C++11 decided to promote `consume` results to effectively `acquire` when passing across function boundaries*.  Maybe I omitted some steps in the explanation that were only obvious to me since I already understand what I meant.  Hmm, probably I started my answer from the wrong end of the question, before fully reading it, and didn't get to the part you were really asking until later.)

Comment: (also related: [Memory order consume usage in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741922)) - todo, update this answer.