# Any operation/fence available weaker than release but still offering synchronize-with semantic?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86, memory-barriers

`std::memory_order_release` and `std::memory_order_acquire` operations provide the synchronize-with semantic.

In addition to that, `std::memory_order_release` guarantees that all loads and stores can't be reordered past the release operation.

Questions:

1. Is there anything in C++20/23 that provides the same synchronized-with semantic but isn't as strong as `std::memory_order_release` such that loads can be reordered past the release operation?  In a hope that the out-of-order code is more optimized (by compiler  or by CPU).
2. Let's say there is no such thing in C++20/23, is there any no standard way to do so (e.g. some inline asm) for x86 on linux?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::memory_order_relaxed`?

Comment: @user17732522 loads "after" a release operation can be reordered to precede the release operation but loads "before" the release operation cannot be reordered past the release operation.

Comment: @PasserBy `std::memory_order_relaxed` doesn't have the synchronize-with semantic.

Comment: @HCSF: "*for x86 on linux?*" Um, if there's going to be a platform where this would be meaningful, x86 is *not* that platform.

Comment: @HCSF But that's a consequence of the synchronize-with semantics.

Comment: `memory_order_release` is basically free on x86, only needing to block compile-time reordering. [C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314179). Like Nicol says, x86 is a silly choice to ask about; PowerPC would be more interesting and has more kinds of barrier instruction.

Comment: As @user17732522 points out, if loads could be reordered past your hypothetical `weak_release` store, then it wouldn't *have* the synchronize-with semantics.  The point of synchronize-with is that an acquire load and a release store can protect a critical section.  If a load of some object from within the critical section could pass the release store, then it would no longer be protected, and might race with some other thread that was told it could safely write that object.

Answer (score 2):

ISO C++ only has three orderings that apply to stores: `relaxed`, `release` and `seq_cst`.  Relaxed is clearly too weak, and `seq_cst` is strictly stronger than `release`.  So, no.

The property that neither loads nor stores may be reordered past a release store is *necessary* to provide the synchronize-with semantics that you want, and can't be weakened in any way I can think of without breaking them.  The point of synchronize-with is that a release store can be used as the end of a critical section.  Operations within that critical section, both loads and stores, have to stay there.

Consider the following code:

```
std::atomic<bool> go{false};
int crit = 17;

void thr1() {
    int tmp = crit;
    go.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
}

void thr2() {
    while (!go.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        // delay
    }
    crit = 42;
}
```

This program is free of data races and must output `17`.  This is because the release store in thr1 synchronizes with the final acquire load in thr2, the one that returns `true` (thus taking its value from the store).  This implies that the load of `crit` in thr1 happens-before the store in `thr2`, so they don't race, and the load does not observe the store.

If we replaced the release store in thr1 with your hypothetical half-release store, such that the load of `crit` could be reordered after `go.store(true, half_release)`, then that load might take place any amount of time later.  It could in particular happen concurrently with, or even after, the store of `crit` in thr2.  So it could read `42`, or garbage, or anything else could happen.  This should not be possible if `go.store(true, half_release)` really did synchronize with `go.load(acquire)`.

Comment: Your `thr1` reader never uses the `tmp` it loaded.  I think you meant to print `tmp` instead of loading `crit` again (with seq_cst) after the critical section.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I did remove the `seq_cst` comment: in this example the variable `crit` is intentionally not atomic.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I got so distracted by the `tmp` issue that I didn't read the rest of if carefully!  Looks good now.

Answer (score 1):

#### ISO C++

In ISO C++, no, `release` is the minimum for the writer side of doing some (possibly non-atomic) stores and then storing a `data_ready` flag.  Or for locking / mutual exclusion, to keep loads before a release store and stores after an acquire load (no LoadStore reordering).  Or anything else *happens-before* gives you. (C++'s model works in terms of guarantees on what a load can or must see, not in terms of local reordering of loads and stores from a coherent cache.  I'm talking about how they're [mapped into asm for normal ISAs](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html).)  `acq_rel` RMWs or `seq_cst` stores or RMWs also work, but are stronger than `release`.

---

#### Asm with weaker guarantees that might be sufficient for some cases

In asm for some platform, *perhaps* there might be something weaker you could do, but it wouldn't be fully happens-before. I don't think there are any requirements on release which are superfluous to happens-before and normal acq/rel synchronization.  (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).

**Some common use cases for acq/rel sync only needs StoreStore ordering on the writer side, LoadLoad on the reader side**.  (e.g. producer / consumer with one-way communication, non-atomic stores and a `data_ready` flag.)  **Without the LoadStore ordering requirement**, I could imagine either the writer or reader being cheaper on some platforms.

Perhaps PowerPC or RISC-V?  I checked what compilers do [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0Aint+load(std::atomic_int+%26a)+%7B%0A++++return+a.load(std::memory_order_acquire)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+store(std::atomic_int+%26a)+%7B%0A++++return+a.store(1,+std::memory_order_release)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:58.557191289707475,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+RISC-V+rv32gc+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:37.13652946209222,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:rv32-clang,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+RISC-V+rv32gc+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:29.530137204574462,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppcg1220,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-mregnames%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+power+gcc+12.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for `a.load(acquire)` and `a.store(1, release)`.

```
# clang(trunk) for RISC-V -O3
load(std::atomic<int>&):     # acquire
        lw      a0, 0(a0)    # apparently RISC-V just has barriers, not acquire *operations*
        fence   r, rw        # but the barriers do let you block only what is necessary
        ret
store(std::atomic<int>&):    # release
        fence   rw, w
        li      a1, 1
        sw      a1, 0(a0)
        ret
```

If `fence r` and/or `fence w` exist and are ever cheaper than `fence r,rw` or `fence   rw, w`, then yes, RISC-V can do something slightly cheaper than acq/rel.  Unless I'm missing something, that would still be strong enough if you just want loads after an acquire load see stores from before a release store, but don't care about LoadStore: Others loads staying before a release store, and others stores staying after an acquire load.

CPUs naturally want to load early and store late to hide latencies, so it's usually not much of a burden to actually block LoadStore reordering on top of blocking LoadLoad or StoreStore.  At least that's true for an ISA as long as it's possible to get the ordering you need without having to use a much stronger barrier.  (i.e. when the only option that meets the minimum requirement is far beyond it, like 32-bit ARMv7 where you'd need a `dmb ish` full barrier that also blocked StoreLoad.)

- https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ - as Preshing notes, LoadStore reordering is usually only useful on cache-miss loads.  ("Instruction*" reordering isn't the best way to think of it, though; the important part is the ordering of access to cache.  Stores don't access cache until they come out the far end of the [store buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram); executing a store just writes data and address into the store buffer.  Loads do access cache when they execute.)
- [How does memory reordering help processors and compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725497/how-does-memory-reordering-help-processors-and-compilers)

---

#### `release` is free on x86; other ISAs are more interesting.

**`memory_order_release` is basically free on x86, only needing to block compile-time reordering.**  (See *[C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314179/c-how-is-release-and-acquire-achieved-on-x86-only-using-mov)* - The x86 memory model is program order plus a store-buffer with store forwarding).

x86 is a silly choice to ask about; something like PowerPC where there are multiple different choices of light-weight barrier would be more interesting.  Turns out it only needs one barrier each for acquire and release, but seq_cst needs multiple different barriers before and after.

PowerPC asm looks like this for load(acquire) and store(1,release) -

```
load(std::atomic<int>&):
        lwz %r3,0(%r3)
        cmpw %cr0,%r3,%r3     #; I think for a data dependency on the load
        bne- %cr0,$+4         #; never-taken, if I'm reading this right?
        isync                 #; instruction sync, blocking the front-end until older instructions retire?
        blr
store(std::atomic<int>&):
        li %r9,1
        lwsync               # light-weight sync = LoadLoad + StoreStore + LoadStore.  (But not blocking StoreLoad)
        stw %r9,0(%r3)
        blr
```

I don't know if `isync` is always cheaper than `lwsync` which I'd think would also work there; I'd have thought stalling the front-end might be worse than imposing some ordering on loads and stores.

I suspect the reason for the compare-and-branch instead of just `isync` ([documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=set-isync-ics-instruction-synchronize-instruction)) is that a load can retire from the back-end ("complete") once it's known to be non-faulting, before the data actually arrives.

(x86 doesn't do this, but weakly-ordered ISAs do; it's how you get LoadStore reordering on CPUs like ARM, with in-order or out-of-order exec.  Retirement goes in program order, but stores can't commit to L1d cache until *after* they retire.  x86 requiring loads to produce a value before they can retire is one way to guarantee LoadStore ordering.  *[How is load->store reordering possible with in-order commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215031/how-is-load-store-reordering-possible-with-in-order-commit)*)

So on PowerPC, the compare into condition-register 0 (`%cr0`) has a data dependency on the load, can can't execute until the data arrives.  Thus can't complete.  I don't know why there's also an always-false branch on it.  I think the `$+4` branch destination is the `isync` instruction, in case that matters.  I wonder if the branch could be omitted if you only need LoadLoad, not LoadStore?  Unlikely.

---

IDK if ARMv7 can maybe block just LoadLoad or StoreStore.  If so, that would be a big win over `dmb ish`, which compilers use because they also need to block LoadStore.

---

#### Loads cheaper than acquire: `memory_order_consume`

This is the useful hardware feature that ISO C++ doesn't currently expose (because `std::memory_order_consume` is defined in a way that's too hard for compilers to implement correctly in every corner case, without introducing more barriers.  Thus it's deprecated, and compilers handle it the same as `acquire`).

Dependency ordering (on all CPUs except DEC Alpha) makes it safe to load a pointer and deref it without any barriers or special load instructions, and still see the pointed-to data if the writer used a release store.

If you want to do something cheaper than ISO C++ `acq`/`rel`, the load side is where the savings are on ISAs like POWER and ARMv7.  (Not x86; full acquire is free).  To a much lesser extent on ARMv8 I think, as `ldapr` should be cheapish.

See *[C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280633/c11-the-difference-between-memory-order-relaxed-and-memory-order-consume/59832012#59832012)* for more, including a talk from Paul McKenney about how Linux uses plain loads (effectively `relaxed`) to make the read side of RCU very very cheap, with no barriers, as long as they're careful to not write code where the compiler can optimize away the data dependency into just a control dependency or nothing.

Also related:

- [Memory order consume usage in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741148/memory-order-consume-usage-in-c11)
- [C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280633/c11-the-difference-between-memory-order-relaxed-and-memory-order-consume/59832012#59832012)
- [When should you not use [[carries_dependency]]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126983/when-should-you-not-use-carries-dependency)
- [Are memory orderings: consume, acq_rel and seq_cst ever needed on Intel x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719680/are-memory-orderings-consume-acq-rel-and-seq-cst-ever-needed-on-intel-x86)
- [[[carries_dependency]] what it means and how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113244/carries-dependency-what-it-means-and-how-to-implement)
- [What does memory_order_consume really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336409/what-does-memory-order-consume-really-do)