# Memory ordering and RMW operations

Tags: c, c11, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Suppose I make two relaxed modifications to two atomic objects in `thread0`, one per each object, and then make `thread1` observe the modification that came second in `thread0`.
Now without memory fences, if `thread1` were to try and load the first object, it might not get the newly stored value (without release on the store and an acquire on the observation), but what if it does an atomic read-modify-write operation on it?

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
int _Atomic atoInt = 0;
_Atomic _Bool atoBool= 0;

void thread0(void){
    atomic_store_explicit(&atoInt,42,memory_order_relaxed);

    atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_seq_cst); //prevent compiler reordering

    atomic_store_explicit(&atoBool,1,memory_order_relaxed);
}

void thread1(void){
    //observe the 0 => 1 transition
    while(0==(atomic_load_explicit(&atoBool,memory_order_relaxed))){}

    atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_seq_cst); //prevent compiler reordering

    //could still get the stale value because release/acquire wan't used
    assert(
        0==atomic_load_explicit(&atoInt,memory_order_relaxed)
        || 42==atomic_load_explicit(&atoInt,memory_order_relaxed)
    );

    //should hold regardless because it's an RMW?
    assert(42==atomic_fetch_sub_explicit(&atoInt,1,memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

Based on my understanding of how cache coherence and fences work, I believe the RMW operation must necessarily get the new value.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think anything in the ISO C standard formally guarantees that an RMW would see the stored value.  With compile-time reordering of the stores (since they're also both relaxed), it's super easy for the assert to fail even on a strongly-ordered machine like x86.

Comment: A more interesting computer-architecture question is whether any real or hypothetical ISA could break dependency-ordering for loads but not RMWs.  (The HW behaviour that most ISAs have, which `memory_order_consume` was intended to expose to programmers, but the design proved impractical, so real code like Linux RCU uses effectively `relaxed` loads and writes code like this where the compiler can't replace the load result with a constant or otherwise break the data depency e.g. by turning it into a control dependency (branch).)

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright. And if compile-time reordering is prevented (I guess `atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` should do it?)?

Comment: The only real-world ISA without dependency ordering is DEC Alpha ([Memory order consume usage in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55741148)).  Hypothetical things that could break dependency-ordering include value-prediction for loads.  If that's what you're thinking of, then yeah perhaps, since an atomic RMW can't retire until the store commits to L1d cache, but stores need to be non-speculative, so all prior speculation has to be confirmed before the store side of an atomic RMW can commit.

Comment: `atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst)` would fix it for x86, but weakly-ordered ISAs could still commit the stores to L1d cache out of order unless you use `atomic_thread_fence(release)` between them, or make the second one a `release` store.  Then you're left with the question of reordering dependent loads.  ISO C11 I'm pretty sure doesn't promise anything unless you use a `release` store and at least a `consume` load, but the only real implementation that could even possibly be "weird" with release stores but relaxed loads is DEC Alpha.  And then yeah, maybe not in practice with RMW.

Comment: Are you asking a [language-lawyer] question about the memory-model formalism, or a [cpu-architecture] question about how it could be possible in practice?  I'm pretty sure the language-lawyer answer is trivially simple, that relaxed guarantees nothing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was approaching it more in terms of practice (store buffers & invalidate queues causing hardware inter-thread reordering & RMW ops needing to synchronize cores) but I guess a mixed answer would be ideal -- it's a theoretical question anyway, in real practice I have no problem slapping the release/acquire on there considering it costs nothing extra on my x86-64). Anyway I simplified the code a bit (no more ptr dependencies and put the signal-atomic fences in there).

Comment: With only a signal fence (not thread fence), I'm pretty sure real ISAs other than x86-64 can fail the RMW assert, since the stores can be visible to other threads in the opposite order like I mentioned earlier.  The interesting question is when the stores are required to become visible in order, leaving just the question of whether a relaxed load can reorder with a later relaxed RMW.

Comment: "_my understanding of how cache coherence_" You aren't using `volatile` so...