# How to create extension for RedirectToAction?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

An existing RedirectToAction signature is

```
RedirectToAction(string action, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

I wish to make.

```
RedirectToAction(RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

So I created the following

```
public static class MvcControllerExtension
{
    public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction
        (this Controller controller, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        return controller.RedirectToAction
                    (routeValues["Action"].ToString(), routeValues);
    }
}
```

However, the IDE for that code is showing a `Recursive Call` because it can only see itself.

It does not see this signature.
[image]

I have included `using System.Web.Mvc;` in the extension class.

How can I fix this? thanks.

**Additional:**

Here is the extention source code.
Note the recursive symbol.

### (Sorry, SO is having issues uploading images to imgur.com. Will retry soon).

Comment: This appears to be the same problem as this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118064/extension-methods-overloading-in-c-does-it-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do an extension? `RedirectToAction` is a helper method in the `Controller` class, so why not create yours as a protected method in *your* base controller class?

```
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
   protected RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
   {
      return RedirectToAction(routeValues["Action"].ToString(), routeValues);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Valamas It might also be helpful to note, the reason you were having an issue is because `Controller.RedirectToAction` is marked `protected`.  It is only intended to be used from within a `Controller`, so that's why your extension method cannot "see" it, and can only "see" itself.  Change the name of your extension method, and the error will be much easier to spot.

Comment: I see that now. I also got carried away with extension madness on this one. thank you for adding that

Answer (score 0):

What namespace is MvcControllerExtension in - it must be in the same namespace or have the import for it.

Comment: The problem is before the usage of the code. The error I am having is at the source of the extension. I have updated my post with the error.