# Overloading Extension Methods

Tags: c#, excelpackage

Is it possible to overload Extension Methods?

I did something like this

```
    public static ExcelWorksheet CreateSheet(this ExcelPackage thisPackage, List<Document> list)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = thisPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Documents");
        return worksheet;
    }
    public static ExcelWorksheet CreateSheet(this ExcelWorksheet thisPackage, List<Book> list)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = thisPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Books");
        return worksheet;
    }
```

In this case, It recognizes only the first method as an extension method and Ignores the second method without any Compiler Warnings or Errors.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118064/extension-methods-overloading-in-c-does-it-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't overloading here as the extension methods are on different objects, `ExcelPackage` and `ExcelWorksheet`. Overloading extension methods **is** acceptable though.

Comment: I just realized my mistake. Thanks